# Flutter - The argument type 'File' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File?'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, imagepicker

I am building a Flutter app and currently I am trying to implement a method that can pick an image file but I am getting an error that says The argument type 'File' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File?'. Does anyone have an idea on how I can solve this?

```
getImageDialogue(ImageSource source) async {
    final ImagePicker _pickedFile = ImagePicker();

    final XFile? image = await _pickedFile.pickImage(source: source);

    if (image != null) {
      media.add(EventMediaModel(
//This is the line where I am getting the error on File(image.path)
          image: File(image.path), video: null, isVideo: false));

      setState(() {});

      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Comment: since you had validate that `image!= null`, you can use `!` to your media. 
`image: File(image!.path).....`

Comment: I tried that and it said "The '!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null.
Try removing the '!' operator "

Comment: You probably have two different types that are both named `File`.  I don't know what `EventMediaModel` is or where it comes from, but the Dart extension for VS Code can let you easily inspect `EventMediaModel` to determine what `File` type it expects.

Comment: EventMediaModel is a model class I made and it expects the type File?

Comment: So yes it turns out I had two different types of File. One was in the html package whilst the other was in the IO. But thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It might help to create a non-nullable "image" variable in your EventMediaModel.

```
Future<void> getImageDialogue(ImageSource source) async {
  final ImagePicker _pickedFile = ImagePicker();
  final XFile? image = await _pickedFile.pickImage(source: source);

  if (image != null && image.path != '') {
    File file = File(image.path);
    media.add(EventMediaModel(image: file, video: null, isVideo: false));
    setState(() {});
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I figured out that the problem was I had two different types of File. One was in the html package whilst the other was in the IO